# The poles of order $m$ of $g$ are zeros of order $2m$ of $f$

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose that $\phi _{i},$ $\left( i=1,2,3\right) $ triple of holomorphic
complex functions satisfy $\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\phi _{1}^{2}+\phi _{2}^{2}+\phi _{3}^{2}=0 \\ 
\left\vert \phi _{1}\right\vert ^{2}+\left\vert \phi _{2}\right\vert
^{2}+\left\vert \phi _{3}\right\vert ^{2}\neq 0%
\end{array}%
\right. $.

Define $\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
f=\left( \phi _{1}-i\phi _{2}\right)  \\  
g=\frac{\phi _{3}}{\phi _{1}-i\phi _{2}}
\end{array}
\right. $

and show that $g$ is meromorphic and $f$ is holomorphic and that the poles of
order $m$ of $g$ are zeros of order $2m$ of $f$.

I already tried using the equivalences for poles and zero of a function but
I could not.

Comment: If $g$ is holomorphic then surely it has no poles? Do you mean meromorphic?

Comment: @George Sorry, the text is misspelled. I'll edit.

Comment: While you're editing maybe also take care of "trilpe"

Answer (score 1):

We compute
$$g^2f=\frac{\phi_3^2}{\phi_1-i\phi_2}=-\frac{\phi_1^2+\phi_2^2}{\phi_1-i\phi_2}=-(\phi_1+i\phi_2) $$
and see that this is holomorphic. To show that every pole of order $m$ of $g$ is a root of order $2m$ of $f$, it suffices to show that the right hand side has no zero that is also a pole of $g$.
Indeed, if $\phi_1(z)+i\phi_2(z)=0$ and $\phi_1(z)-i\phi_2(z)=0$, then $\phi_1(z)=\phi_2(z)=0$, hence $\phi_3(z)=0$ by the first condition, contradicting the second condition.

Comment: I'm sorry, but because that to show that every pole of order is a root of order $2m$ of $f$ it suffices to show that the right hand side has no zero that is also a pole of $g$?

Comment: @ Hagen, are you there?